# NSURLConnection: Resume functionality

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, download, foundation

I'm writing a download manager in Objective-C, and I have it working with resume functionality. I am writing the data to disk as I receive it so that if the download is interrupted for any reason, it should pick up where it left off. Apple says you should expect one or more `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response` events. In this event, they say you should reset any data you have previously received because your download is being redirected and the bytes you have already received is invalid, so I delete the existing file and recreate with 0 bytes. But if I receive this event multiple times, I have to delete data I have previously received in the form of a partial download, defeating the purpose of resume functionality. Is there a solution to this?

The solution I have come up with is: only reset the data on`- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response` events I receive after the first. This would fix the majority of cases (I would think). Is this logically sound? Is there a better alternative? How likely is a file download to fire multiple `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response` events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multipart/x-mixed-replace` is used when the server wants to replace what it has already given you with something else.  Deleting everything you've downloaded so far is the only sensible option, you can't resume downloading something when the server is telling you to throw it away and use something else instead.

> How likely is a file download to fire multiple - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response events?

Extremely unlikely.  It's only ever used in certain types of streaming, not for anything you'd need a download manager for.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to use a library from someone who has already solved this problem, ASIHttpRequest is what I use.  It can be found [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

Search for 'Resuming' on that page

Comment: Please note that ASIHttpRequest project is no longer maintained. But you can always check the code how resume is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

This is nice and clean library that, I think, has functionality that you need:
https://github.com/Anviking/DownloadManager